# BigQuery Relation between service account and project

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am using Node library to integrate my application with BigQuery. I am planning to accept projectId, Email and private key from user and then I  will validate credentials by making call to getDataset operation with limit 1  This will ensure that all 3 parameters passed by user are proper.

But then I realized that even if I pass different valid project ID, my call to getDataset passes. Operation gets datasets from that project. So I was wondering if Service account is not linked to  project. Any idea how I can validate these three parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

A **service account** key has some attributes inside it including project_id, private_key, client_email and many others. In this [page](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) you can find how to configure the credentials to use the client libraries.

Basically, the first step is creating a service account and download a JSON key (I suppose that you already completed this step)

Then you need to set an environment variable in your system so your application can access the credentials.

For Linux/Mac you can do that running:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

For Windows (using CMD):

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]
```